# Single Table with Two columns (tables) in two column article

Tags: tables, two-column

I want to create a single table in two column article, where internally table contains two tables, one in each column. The following picture shows the requirements.
[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: `\begin{table*}\caption{Caption}\begin{tabular}{ccc}  ... \end{tabular}\hfill\begin{tabular}{ccc}  ... \end{tabular}\end{table*}`

Comment: See the answer posted by me which can be your starting point. I answered this question only because I remembered my first faltering days in the early nineties. Yes, TeXSE was not there in those days.

In future, this community would expect a more focused question from you with a MWE. We particularly dislike, "Do my job for me" type requests.

And welcome to TeXSE.

Comment: Do tell us which document class you use, please. Also, please tell us whether the table's overall caption should be centered or should be placed just over the left-hand part. Finally, is the right-hand part a direct continuation of the material shown on the left, or is it a separate entity?

Comment: @Masroor Thank you very much. I spent a lot of time, although my question shows that I asked without any struggle. 
However, I will follow the instructions next time and will give my attempt as an example.

Comment: @TechieFort You are always welcome. As per my experience, you need to show some effort to get an answer. And if there is some code which can be compiled easily, you are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will be a good starting point for you. For other tweaks (including centering of individual tables and captions), you need to study a bit more. Please see these, [1](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/tables), [2](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/beginners/latex-tables/), [3](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/LaTeX/TableHelp1.pdf).

For the particular issue of placing a double column float at page bottom, [this article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111beet-banner.pdf) is a good read.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!b]
  \caption{Caption.}
  \label{tab:tbl1}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    X&Y&X\\\hline
    1&2&3\\
    4&5&6\\
    1&2&3\\
    4&5&6\\
    1&2&3\\
    4&5&6\\
    1&2&3\\
    4&5&6\\
    7&8&9\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    A&B&C\\\hline
    a&b&c\\
    d&e&f\\
    g&h&i\\
    j&k&l\\
    m&n&o\\
    p&q&r\\
    s&t&u\\
    v&w&x\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. You may want to point out that the `\centering` statement (immediately after `\label`) is needed only if the `\hfill` directive were omitted.

Comment: @Mico I could not decide what actually he is asking for. Centered individuals tables, both caption and individual tables centered, or something else. I wanted to compress all these issues inside that blanket statement of "other tweaks".
Putting a hint anyway.

Comment: @mico Also, those issues pointed out in your comment are the ones based on which the solution may change, including the use of `longtable`.